Dimension of hom spaces between indecomposable modules
Undergraduate-Level Background
Let $A$ be an Artin algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $C = Rep(A)$ denotes the category of $k$-linear, $k$-finite dimensional representations of $A$. I am interested in computing the dimensions of the hom spaces in $C$.
If $A$ is semisimple, then every object in $C$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of some simple objects $i, j, \ldots$. The $k$-dimension of $Hom_C(i,j)$ is the dirac delta $\delta_{ij}$ (by Schur's lemma for algebraically closed fields). This provides a full answer to the problem.
If $A$ is not semisimple, each simple object $i$ corresponds to a projective indecomposable module $P_i$, which is isomorphic to the projective cover of $i$. Hence, the dimension of $Hom_C(P_i, j)$ is again $\delta_{ij}$. This partially answers the problem for $Hom_C(X,Y)$, where X is projective and Y is a direct sum of simples.
Questions
Undergraduate courses usually stop here. And I wonder what's beyond this. I am aware of Auslander-Reiten theory, but I am not sure how one can compute the dimensions using the AR quiver and almost split sequences.
Let me list the remaining cases in order of difficulty.
Compute the $dim_k Hom_C(X,Y)$ where

$X$ and $Y$ are projective.
$X$ is projective, and $Y$ is general.
$X$ and $Y$ are equivalent to finite direct sums of (not necessarily projective) indecomposable modules.

In particular, are there sets of modules $\{J_a\}, \{J_a^*\}$ "dual" to the set of indecomposable modules $\{I_a\}$ in the sense that
$$dim_k Hom_C(I_a, J_b) = \delta_{ab} = dim_k Hom_C(J_a^*, I_b)?$$

You might like to read my "Representations and Cohomology I" especially Lemma 1.7.5 and Theorem 5.11.1.

Also my paper with Richard Parker from 1984.

Thanks for pointing out that I need "algebraic closeness"; edited. And I appreciate your results on $k[G]$-modules. Are there general techniques? Or it is so elusive that we must focus on special case?

It works the same way for any finite dimensional algebra. The dual elements are not modules but differences of almost split sequences terminating, respectively beginning with your module.
